# OAuth2 with Google and Spring Boot - I can't log out

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I've been trying to get a successful Oauth2 login with Google and Spring Boot for a while now. This only works partially. Why partly - because I can't manage the logout or when I pressed the logout button I see an empty, white browser page with my URL (http://localhost:8181/ben/"). After a refresh of the page I get error from google, but if I open a new tab, enter my url, I'm still logged in to google, because I can see my user, which I'm outputting to my react application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
}

@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(Principal principal) {
    return principal;
}

@RequestMapping("/logout")
public String fetchSignoutSite(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Cookie rememberMeCookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", "");
    rememberMeCookie.setMaxAge(0);
    response.addCookie(rememberMeCookie);

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null) {
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }

    auth.getPrincipal();
    return "redirect:/ben/login";
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ben/*").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8181/ben/login").invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
}
```

My application.yml file looks like this:

```
# Spring Boot configuration
spring:
  profiles:
active: google
# Spring Security configuration
security:
 oauth2:
   client:
     clientId: 415772070383-3sapp4flauo6iqsq8eag7knpcii50v9k.apps.googleusercontent.com
  clientSecret: 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
  accessTokenUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
  userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
  clientAuthenticationScheme: form
  scope:
    - email
    - profile
resource:
  userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
  preferTokenInfo: true
# Server configuration
server:
port: 8181
 servlet:
  context-path: /ben
```

[image]

Comment: did you find solution for this issue. I am also facing similar issue. After successful logout, without entering user credentials last user able to access home page when I hit login url.

Answer (score 0):

That fetchSignoutSite only emptying the JsessionId and logging out from Spring Security context. So you would still need to add part where you go to google and sign out from there which I have no experience on implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways, but I'm afraid both of them suggest relying on browser action. Original article here: https://groups.google.com/g/google-api-javascript-client/c/PCs8xXV4wxk?pli=1

TL;DR

1. Expose the link https://accounts.google.com/logout as part of logout action somewhere in your user interface.
2. Add hidden iframe with src pointing to the same url to the document for a couple of seconds and then remove it hoping there was no internet connection drop at that time.

I've chosen the first one, displayed a logout screen with the button link.